# How to pad tuple data in Tensorflow for batching?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am unable to perform padded batching dataset.padded_batch() , in Tensorflow, here is my code :

this code throws an error, doesn't work, I think its because for some reason I am using my own code to calculate MFCC, but it works if I don't call padded_batch

I am getting the following error :

" InvalidArgumentError: All elements in a batch must have the same rank as the padded shape for component0: expected rank 1 but got element with rank 2
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,?], [?,?], [?,?]], output_types=[DT_DOUBLE, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]] "

```
def _read_py_function(audio, label):
    audio = audio_to_mfcc(audio)
    original_length=audio.shape[0]

    #if audio.shape[0] < timesteps:
     #   original_length=audio.shape[0]
       # print(original_length)

    #elif audio.shape[0] >= timesteps:
     #   original_length=timesteps


    #audio=normalized(pad(audio) , axis=1 )
   # audio=pad(audio)

    return audio ,label, original_length

dataset = tf.contrib.data.TextLineDataset("hardik_250_docker.csv")
dataset=dataset.map(decode_csv)



dataset = dataset.map(
    lambda audio, label: tuple(tf.py_func(
        _read_py_function, [audio, label], [tf.double, label.dtype, tf.int64])))


shapes=([None]  , [None], [None])
dataset=dataset.padded_batch(2, padded_shapes=shapes)
```

Comment: Please include the error message in the question

Comment: I added the exact error, I am getting